# jQuery UI only resizable on one side

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

So I just imported jQuery UI to add some pazzaz to my site, and I'm trying to make a Bootstrap modal draggable and resizable. I've got draggability down, but resizability is giving me a rough time.

I can only resize my modal on one side, the right one.

The HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Export Window</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('#modalContent').resizable();
```

Am I missing something here?

EDIT: My mistake, it appears its resizable on the right and bottom, but I'd like it to be resizable also on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
$('#modalContent').resizable({
    handles: 'e, w'
});
```

Allows me to resize horizontally.